# Найти все числа от 2 до n

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Найти и вывести все целые числа в диапазоне от 2 до n, для которых в двоичном представлении числа количество нулей меньше количества единиц.

Comment: Лидирующе нули есть или нет?

Comment: А вопрос какой?

Comment: Нужно проверить: если в двоичном придставлении числа больше едениц чем нулей, то вывести это число.

Comment: где в предложении "нужно проверить: если в двоичном придставлении числа больше едениц чем нулей , то вывести это число" вопросительный знак?

Comment: @fogbit знак вопроса в данном случае не нужен. <br />
@qwerty12359 можно и не реагировать сразу на всякий оффтопик <br />

Так в чём суть проблемы? Если это учебное задание, то просто для каждого числа пройдитесь по всем битами посчитайте кого сколько.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну например так (незначащие нули впереди не учитываются)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    int n;
    vector<int> v;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        int diff=0, k = i;
        while(k) {
            if(k & 1) diff--;
            else diff++;
            k >>= 1;
        }
        if(diff < 0) v.push_back(i);
    }
    vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
    while(it < v.end()) {
        cout << *it++;
        if(it < v.end()) cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну выводить по возрастанию никто не просил, так что можно сделать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned n, o = 0, z = 1, p = 0, q, c;

  scanf("%u", &n);

  for (q=1; q<2*n; ++q)
  {
    c = q ^ (q>>1);
    if (c & (p^c)) ++o, --z; else --o, ++z;
    p = c;
    if (o > z && c < n && c != 1) printf("%d ", c);
    if (o == 1) ++z;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Начинаю кодить, так что думаю выложить своё решение на Си:**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int n = 0, num10 = 2, num10f = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Enter n.   [2;n]\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (num10; num10 <= n; num10++)
    {
        num10f = num10;

        while (num10f / 2 != 0)
        {
            if (num10f % 2 == 0)
                i++;
            else
                j++;

            num10f /= 2;
        }

        if (j >= i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", num10);
        }

        j = 0, i = 0;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Аннулирую свой предыдущий комментарий - вопрос задан опытным участником форума на удивление коряво, что поставило меня в тупик, тем не менее все сказанное в комментарии по поводу джентльменских соглашений на форуме действует.